# Access Youtube Channel ID once signed in though Firebase GoogleAuthProvider

Tags: firebase-authentication, youtube-data-api

I've setup a basic Firebase authentication app which uses Google. I've passed the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
```

When logging in, it states that it is gaining permission to manage my Youtube Account, but the response I get back has nothing relevant to Youtube in it, such as a channelId.

Even when doing a simple $http.get request against the logged in accounts Youtube subscriptions I get the following response:

```
The request uses the <code>mine</code> parameter but is not properly authorized.
```

So would I need to login through Google, then authenticate again once signed in to access my Youtube account?

Sample login:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl");

$scope.login = function () {

    Auth.$signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Signed in as:", result.user.uid);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Are you using the returned access token result.credential.accessToken to query the youtube endpoint? The results are not directly returned from the Firebase Auth API.

Comment: Thanks for responding @bojeil. Ive previously used the google api to sign in and get access to my youtube bits using the gapi.client. I've stored the access token in localStorage for the time being but I am unsure how to use it against the youtube endpoints - any words of wisdom would be great! My current prototype not using firebase is here as well : http://sutsurikeru.com/#/

Comment: Managed to solve it! will post my solution soon!

Comment: Waiting for OP...

Comment: @quantomworks Posted my solution - let me know if it makes sense as I left some logic in there for my own App which would need stripping out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies in the delay.

Here is how I solved this problem. When logging in using Firebase with Google as a provider, I get the access_token given by Google and query YouTubes API to get the correct channel.

An example of my login function is below:

```
        this.loginMainGoogle = function (event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(function _firebaseSignIn(googleUser) {
                var unsubscribe = $rootScope.authObj.$onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
                    unsubscribe();

                    // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
                    if (!_isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
                        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
                        console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse());
                        var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                            googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);

                        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
                        return $rootScope.authObj.$signInWithCredential(credential)
                            .then(function (result) {

                                var ytToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token;
                                localStorage.setItem('gToken', ytToken);
                                $rootScope.tokenerino = ytToken;

                                $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true&access_token=" + ytToken)
                                .then(function(response) {
                                    $rootScope.myChan = response.data.items[0].id;
                                    localStorage.setItem('myChannelId', $rootScope.myChan);
                                    updateYTChannel(result.uid, response.data.items[0].id);
                                });

                                $rootScope.currentLoginStatus = true;
                                $rootScope.notification("You Have Signed In");

                                //Don't redirect them if they login via a YouTube playlist
                                if ($location.path().indexOf('playlists') !== 1) {
                                    $state.go('mymusic');
                                }

                            }, function errorCallback(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    }

                })

            });

        }
```

I store the Channel for the user in Firebase, but you can put it in localStorage if you want. The only problem is that the access_token only lasts for 1 hour. Hopefully this helps anyone and if a better solution has been found - feel free to share!