# How to fix 401 errors with YouTube API queries?

Tags: swift, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[The problem is solved, I actually just can't select my answer as the solution yet.]

I'm working on a video upload feature for a mobile app, with YouTube Data API; but I keep having a 401 error at the query's execution.

I'm using Firebase to provide me OAuth & API keys from Google Developer.

---

I tried to see if the PLIST file furnished by Firebase suffered any change, and even with an other.

I tried to reset the iOS Simulator, to uninstall the app and to terminate the permissions from my account for the app through `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()`.

I tried to see with other StackOverFlow questions, but they all are about other languages, or even "raw" HTTP requests.

---

In my AppDelegate file, I have those lines for the connection with Firebase and Google:

```swift
FirebaseApp.configure()
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
```

and this method (and a very similar one that I won't show here):

```swift
func application( _ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any ) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle( url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation )
}
```

In my controller associated class, I have those methods to create the query:

```swift
private func uploadVideo( withVideoObject video: GTLRYouTube_Video, resumeUploadLocationURL locationURL: URL? ) throws {
    let query = try uploadQuery( _video: video, resumeUploadLocationURL: locationURL )!

    // [ progress related feedback ]

    YouTubeUploadController.uploadFileTicket = self.service.executeQuery( query,
            delegate: self.controller!,
            didFinish: #selector( self.controller!.displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:) ) )
}
private func uploadQuery( _video: GTLRYouTube_Video, resumeUploadLocationURL locationURL: URL? ) throws -> GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosInsert? {
    let fileToUploadURL = URL( fileURLWithPath: "\(self.controller!.uploadPathField)" )
    if !( try! fileToUploadURL.checkPromisedItemIsReachable() ) {
        throw YouTubeCustomError.init( _kind: .fileNotFound )
    }
    // Get a file handle for the upload data.
    let uploadParameters = prepareUploadParameters( fileToUploadURL: fileToUploadURL, locationURL: locationURL )

    return GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosInsert.query( withObject: _video, part: "snippet,status", uploadParameters: uploadParameters )
}
```

It sends an error through `displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)`:
"*This operation couldn't be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)*"

No given failureReason, nor recoverySuggestion.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Response body:**
Here's the GTMSessionFetcher's HTTP answer logs for an upload attempt:

```
Response body: (178 bytes)
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Login Required",
    "errors" : [
      {
        "message" : "Login Required",
        "locationType" : "header",
        "reason" : "required",
        "domain" : "global",
        "location" : "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code" : 401
  }
}
```

---

**Request Headers**

```
Request: POST https://www.googleapis.com/resumable/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&prettyPrint=false
Request headers:
  Accept: application/json
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  User-Agent: org.cocoapods.GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.3.8 google-api-objc-client/3.0 iPhone/12.2 hw/sim (gzip) (GTMSUF/1)
  X-Goog-Upload-Command: start
  X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length: 2614231
  X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type: video/mp4
  X-Goog-Upload-Protocol: resumable
```

Comment: Coud you please try enabling [HTTP logging](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/issues/125#issuecomment-301648345) for us to see the API's JSON response?

Comment: @stvar Edited! Thank you for the suggestion 

Comment: As per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/core_errors#UNAUTHORIZED), your login attempt has failed. Could you also check/post from the logs the initiating HTTP header (editing out any credentials data!)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that... The HTTP request?  Also, I don't find any credentials, is it because of POST or did I miss something? 

Comment: Do you know where I should input those credentials?

Comment: Take for example the *request headers* shown [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/issues/125#issuecomment-301785498). I suspect that yours doesn't have the required [HTTP request header](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#callinganapi) of form `Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: I guess that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853677/8327971) answer is of help.

Comment: I think I have found another solution.
If it works, I will create an answer; but I don't want to steal credit from you while you helped me, so I let you post your own answers if you want to 

Comment: No problem at all. Go ahead and post your solution if already tested.

Comment: Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my case, I was lacking the GTRLService authorizer affectation in my GIDSignInDelegate signIn method:
`service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()`

I assume it can be also done in other methods, but it is the core point in which it is initialized.

---

I did it through an ObjC write accessor, because I didn't find a way to [create/obtain a GTRLService instance in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115031/how-to-create-a-gtlryoutubeservice-instance-for-ios) and I used a ObjC singleton class to obtain it, and I was unsure if we could access the GTRLService instance methods in Swift if it was initialized in ObjC.

```
+ (void)setSharedInstanceAuthorizer:(id <GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol>)_authorizer {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [GTLRYouTubeService new];
    }
    sharedInstance.authorizer = _authorizer;
};
```

---

If that doesn't solve the problem, then @stvar's answers in the comments of the question might actually do.

Comment: Thank you for sharing answer. But now `GTLRYouTubeService` doesn't have `authorizer` property anymore. Then how can i fix that problem? Please let me know. Thank you